# How to send props to children in React Router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have to use fetch in children component, but I don't know how to send props in Route. Is there any option for doing that or do I have to do it some other way?

This is route in my parent component:

```
<Route path={`/beers/:beerId`} component={Beer}/>
```

Then I'd like to use fetch in children component:

```
    fetchData = () => {
    let url = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${this.props.id}`;
    fetch(url, {method: 'get'}).then(resp => resp.json()).then((data) =>
        this.setState({
            data: data
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: Do you want to access `beerId` in `Beer` component?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanna do.

Comment: Find my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `Route` matches, it will inject three props to the component it holds:

- `location`: Information about the current location.
- `history`: Access to the browser history and methods to navigate through.
- `match`: All matched URL parameters.

So, in your `Beer` component you can access the URL param `beerId` using `match.params.beerId`, and your Ajax call:

```
const {beerId} = this.props.match.params;

fetchData = () => {
    let url = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${beerId}`;
    fetch(url, {method: 'get'}).then(resp => resp.json()).then((data) =>
        this.setState({
            data: data
        })
    );    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get the beerId from the URL.You can get it from `this.props.match.params.beerId`.

You can also pass it directly the traditional way using the render method

```
<Route path={`/beers/:beerId`} render={()=><Beer id={YOURID}/>}/>
```

If you're using the render method you can access the id using `this.props.id`. 
But since you already have the beer id in the URL its best if you get it using `this.props.match.params.beerId`.

Comment: This is not what he's asking for. He needs to pass props to a Route.

Comment: @Ben is trying to get the beerId in the child so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `render` attribute of the route. An example would be:

```
<Route path={`/beers/:beerId`} render={(props) => <Beer {...props} beerList={beerList} />} />
```

where `beerList` is a hypothetical function or variable which is passed as a `prop` down to to `<Beer />` component.

Further info: [A Simple React Router v4 Tutorial](https://blog.pshrmn.com/entry/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/)